# TimeLine, items exactly on axis or items with low height timeline

Tags: javascript, css, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I'm not able to overlap or put items on axis in vis.js TimeLine. Like here
 http://www.iftekhar.me/ibm/ibm-project-timeline/ , is it possible without changing source code?

By the way background items are not draggable, so I tried to use range, but my timeline has just 30px height and vis-center isn't visible, so I droped its top to 0px and now in fight with weird vertical movings of my range...

What I'm doing wrong?
http://jsfiddle.net/9a5m5283/just move by mouse left-right and top-bottom

```
// DOM element where the Timeline will be attached
var container = document.getElementById('example-timeline');
// Create a DataSet with data 
var data = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: "2", start: '2018-04-03', end: '2018-04-04', className: "foo", type: 'range'},
    {id: "3", start: '2018-04-02', end: '2018-04-03', type: 'background'}
]);

// Configuration for the Timeline as JSON object
var options = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '30px',
    minHeight: '30px',
    start: new Date() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12,
    min: new Date() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 *30,
    zoomMin: 1000 * 6,
    align: 'auto',
    end: new Date(),
    verticalScroll: true,
    orientation: {axis: 'top', item: 'top' },
    selectable: false,
    itemsAlwaysDraggable: {
        item: true, range: true
    },
    editable: {
        updateTime: true
    },
    margin: 0
};

// Create a Timeline
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, data, options);
var timelineCenterPanel = document.querySelector(".vis-panel.vis-center");
timeline.on("changed", function(props){ 
    document.querySelector(".vis-panel.vis-center").style.top = "0px" 
}) 


.vis-time-axis .vis-text {
    font-size: 70%
}

.vis-time-axis .vis-major {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.vis-time-axis .vis-minor {
    padding-top: 1px;
}

.foo {
    opacity: 0.5;
    height: 35px;
}
```